# Is it possible to disable Image Preview in Chrome CSS / debugger

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

Naturally I move my mouse if I want to inspect, change or copy values.
If you coincidently hover over an image you get this huge preview that blocks the whole interface.

Anyone found a setting to disable this?
It really annoys my debugging experience and it feels like the interface is fighting with me.

I'm pretty sure I never need this preview. The rare times I do I can actually open the link.

[image: Image blocking]